# Mapbox JS markers not being removed using .removeLayer()

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a function that successfully adds markers to a map using the mapbox javascript library. However, I want the function to clear all markers from the map before adding two new ones, so that only two markers are showing at a time.

I have looked at other questions/answers here, but none of them have worked so far; markers are just continually added without being removed.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map(...);

function updateMarkers(d) {
  var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer();
  map.removeLayer(featureLayer);
    getCoordX = d.stn_f_c;
    getCoordX = getCoordX.split(",");
    getCoordY = d.stn_t_c;
  getCoordY = getCoordY.split(",");
    featureLayer = L.marker([getCoordX[0],getCoordX[1]], {
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'bicycle',
            'marker-color': '#66CD00'
        })
    }).addTo(map);
  featureLayer += L.marker([getCoordY[0],getCoordY[1]], {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
      'marker-size': 'large',
      'marker-symbol': 'bicycle',
      'marker-color': '#FF6666'
    })
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'removeLayer' method just removes the layer from your map instance and keeps it intact so you can re-add it later. You'll need to call the `clearLayers()` of L.mapbox.FeatureLayer which will remove all the added features from the layer:

```
featureLayer.clearLayers();
```

Also you're overwriting the reference `featureLayer` which holds your layer instance with an instance of `L.Marker`:

```
featureLayer = L.marker(...);
```

The next marker you're using the `+=` assignment operator on the `featureLayer` reference (which now holds a reference to the first marker) that won't work. It's for adding values, not object instances:

```
featureLayer += L.marker(...);
```

There are two ways to add a single layer (marker, polygon, etc) to a featureLayer, using the `addLayer` method of the featureLayer, or using the `addTo` method of the object you're trying to add:

```
featureLayer.addLayer(marker);
// or
marker.addTo(featureLayer);
```

Another weird thing you're doing is the adding of the coordinates. You split the string value to an array:

```
getCoordX = d.stn_f_c;
getCoordX = getCoordX.split(",");
```

Now (i'm assuming) you have an array with two values, then you're using those seperately and creating an array again:

```
L.marker([getCoordX[0],getCoordX[1]])
```

You can just skip that and just do:

```
L.marker(getCoordX)
```

Which is in fact the same. I've cleaned your code but am unable to test it, so forgive me if i made a freehand error:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map(...);

// Create empty layer
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

function updateMarkers (d) {

    // Clear layer
    featureLayer.clearLayers();

    // Splitting the value and adding it in one go
    L.marker(d.stn_f_c.split(","), {
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'bicycle',
            'marker-color': '#66CD00'
        })
    }).addTo(featureLayer); // Add to the featureLayer

    L.marker(d.stn_t_c.split(","), {
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'bicycle',
            'marker-color': '#FF6666'
        })
    }).addTo(featureLayer);

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the distinction between "hiding" the layer and clearing it. However, `featureLayer.clearLayers();` is still not removing the markers.

Comment: Spotted that, i'm updating my answer as we speak

Comment: You're my hero, iH8! Thanks for the pointers on the "weird" things I was doing. Previously the coordinates needed to be separated, but that's changed since. Thanks for helping me clean it up. Have a good one!